# Flat maximum effect?

Tags: modeling, model-selection, linear-model

I've seen this referred to in relation to model selection but haven't come across a definitive description of it.

What the flat maximum effect?

Comment: I don't think I've seen the phrase used in this context. Who says it, where, and in what context is it used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The flat maximum effect is simply that models with very different coefficients can have very similar performance on a particular prediction or classification task.  When this happens it makes interpreting model coefficients difficult.

One example of where this occurs is in linear regression with multicolinearity of the predictor variables.

As another example, consider a classification problem in which population 1 consists of points very tightly clusters around (-1, 0) and population two consists of points very tightly clustered around around (1,0).  In this situation there are many separating hyperplanes that can be used to produce a perfectly effective linear classifiers.  (x1=0 is one such separating hyperplane, but so is x2=x1 or even x2=0.1x1.)

In terms of the optimization problems solved to fit these kinds of models, what happens is that the maximization has many optimal solutions and thus a "flat maximum."